# How to list all installed GIMP plugins?

Tags: plugins, gimp

I need to use [resynthesizer](https://github.com/bootchk/resynthesizer) plugin in GIMP. I installed `gimp-plugin-registry`, but I am not sure whether it contains mentioned plugin.

How can I retrieve list of all installed plugins in GIMP?

Comment: What are you Ubuntu and gimp versions?

Comment: #steeldriver @steeldriver Ubuntu 20.04 64 bit, GIMP 2.10. Unfortunately compiled version of resynthesizer, available on the GITHUB page, seems to be 32-bit only.

Comment: Since you installed `gimp-plugin-registry`, do you see anything if you run `ls -d /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/r*`?

Comment: @matandked The gui is no good to you? For this there is Help --> Plugin Browser....

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu package search: https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/gimp-plugin-registry please select [list of fies] https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/gimp-plugin-registry/filelist

Search for *resynthesizer*. It is not in the list of provided plugins.

**EDIT**: As we see in the list of files, plugings are installed in /usr/share/gimp/2.0/scripts/. We can list them all with the command:

```
ls /usr/share/gimp/2.0/scripts/
```

We can search for resynthesizer with:

```
ls /usr/share/gimp/2.0/scripts/ | grep resynth
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes it for me easier to understand. However, my question was about list of all installed plugins in GIMP on my computer. Is there a single command to do so?

Comment: Groovy (20.10) != Focal (20.04 LTS). See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=resynthesizer for 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: At least in 20.04, the relevant file(s) appear to be in the plug-ins directory `gimp-plugin-registry: /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/resynthesizer` rather than in the `scripts` directory

Comment: @steeldriver My /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/ doesn't contain this. Where did you find it?

Comment: @chili555 I'm seeing it in the `apt-file` search output on my 20.04 WSL system (don't actually have gimp installed in that, for obvious reasons) and also on my 18.04 box w/ gimp-2.8 + gimp-plugin-registry installed